# Class containing string: what really happens when it's returned from a function?

Tags: c++, c++11, move, rvo

Not that I don't trust my compiler, but I like to know what's going on. Let's say I have

```
struct Foo {
  std::string s;
};
```

and I want to create one of those (on the stack), fill in the very long string, and return it from my function.

```
Foo f() {
  Foo foo {my_very_long_string};
  return foo;
  // OR: return Foo {my_very_long_string};
}
```

I know there's such things as RVO and move semantics; how do I know that they're being used, and at runtime it's not allocating a new string with data on the heap, copying it, and freeing the old one? (Other than my program will get slow.)

Is it using a move constructor to reuse the string data? Or is it using RVO to actually return the same string?

Comment: Compile and check the assembly if you don't trust it.  Before you do anything like that though benchmark the code.  There is no reason to do this if the code performs fine.

Comment: "How do I know that ... at runtime it's not allocating a new string ..., copying it, and freeing the old one?" You are guaranteed this isn't happening. Without RVO, the string will be *moved* rather than *copied*, so there won't be an extra allocation

Comment: This is rather philosophical question. How can you be sure of anything that other people (in this case the standard developers) tell you? I guess you have to trust them at some point. Or dig into everything yourself, but you know, life is short. :)

Comment: There's one case where you do have to be careful -- if you define a destructor (or copy ctor or copy assign), you do NOT get an implicit move ctor defined for you.  So your object becomes unmovable and so copies occur (including of fields that would otherwise be movable)

Comment: _"I know there's such things as RVO and move semantics; how do I know that they're being used"_ (A) Read the Standard or a competent summary of it, to learn when these optimisations *can* occur. (B) Read your (completely unknown) compiler's generated assembly to see whether such optimisations *did* occur.

Comment: @freakish, I guess I'm the philosophical type. :-) But I was hoping there would be some kind of tool, or compiler option (for some mythical compiler, maybe clang-based) that would output what it was doing. Similarly I'd love to have a compiler option that explains which specialization of a template is used, and which overload of an overload set is chosen. Kind of how the Intel compiler can tell you which functions are getting vectorized, or why not. Seems like a tool like this would be very useful for debugging as well as performance optimization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### NRVO or move for named objects

In the function:

```
Foo f() {
  Foo foo{my_very_long_string};
  return foo;
}
```

The object `foo` has a name (i.e.: `foo`), it is a *named* object.

*Named RVO* (NRVO), which is an optional optimization, may occur. If no NRVO takes place, then `foo` is moved, since it is a local object and therefore treated as an rvalue in this context (i.e.: the `return` statement).

---

#### RVO/copy elsion or move for unnamed objects

However, in the function:

```
Foo f() {
  return Foo{my_very_long_string};
}
```

A *unnamed* object, which is the one resulting from `Foo{my_very_long_string}`, is concerned.

- As of C++17, the copy has to be necessarily *elided* (i.e.: same effect as RVO, although different semantics).
- Before C++17, RVO, which was back then an optional optimization, may occur. If it doesn't, then it is moved, since `Foo{my_very_long_string}` is already an rvalue.

---

No heap allocation for a new string will happen in any of the cases above.